# Factory Girl: uninitialized constant non rails project

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, rspec2

I was hoping somebody would be able to help me with a problem I am having with an uninitialized constant error I am receiving when attempting to use factory_girl. I know similar questions have been posted on stack overflow, and I have attempted to find a solution within these posts but to no avail.

I have a non rails project which I am using rspec to test. I wish to use factory_girl to create test data.

So I have my factory defined in a file called users.rb in the spec/factories folder. Factory is as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user do
   email 'root@test.com'
   password 'TestPass'
 end
```

end

I then have a test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "login tests" do

  it "should allow me to login" do
    visit('http://mytestapp.com')
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    login(user.email, user.password)
    should have_content('Welcome!')
  end

end
```

In my spec helper I have

```
require 'factory_girl'
require_rel('factories')

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

However when I run my test I receive the error message "uninitialized constant User"

Please note in the spec_helper file I use the gem reqiure_rel to find the factories folder. I tried using FactoryGirl.find_definitions but when I used this I got the error message "Factory not registered: user". So using require_rel it appears the factory is at least found. In my test file I have also tried using this:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

but I get the same error message.

Has anybody got any idea what I am doing wrong? Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is not the issue with `FactoryGirl`. `RSpec` doesn't see your `User` class. So you should require the file with User class. And it will be better to `describe User` not `login tests`.

Comment: Thanks Ihar! Bit of a rookie mistake on my part, I was not aware that you needed to first create the User class. I created the class User and initialized email and password and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that FactoryGirl relies on the `rspec-rails` gem to locate and autoload models when the associated constants are referenced (e.g. loading `.../app/models/user.rb` when `User` is referenced). If you wanted to operate without that gem, you'd have to enable that autoloading yourself.